# What if Terraform recreates a resource that is referenced inside another state?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

TL;DR: What if Terraform destroys and recreates a resource that is referenced in another resource located in another state file. Would it break the reference in the cloud and cause downtime until I run apply against the other state file?

Hi. I'm using Terraform and Google Cloud Platform. I have the Terraform files related to my applications and microservices separate in each of the application repositories and I also have some other repositories exclusively for some infrastructure resources like VPC, Load Balancer and IAM.

Let's say that the Cloud Functions service that runs one of my microservices is provisioned by Terraform files that are located in the specific microservice repository, which has its own isolated remote state.

In the Load Balancer repository, I have data objects referencing that microservice's remote state so I can reference resources from that state, like the Cloud Functions service that I need to reference when creating its Network Endpoint Groups and Load Balancer backends.

After the example above, I wonder what would happen if I change something in the microservice files causing some resource to be destroyed and recreated. Since the other resources that reference it are located in different repositories and state files, I suppose I would need to run terraform init and apply inside both the repos, am I right or am I overthinking? What would you do to resolve this issue instead?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

If your setup requires managing same resource from two different TF state files, then you are doing it wrong. This is not how TF should be used, and off course it will lead to the issues.

A given resource can only be managed by one TF state file.

Comment: I am not managing the same resource from two different TF state files. The point is that, for example, I need to pass the identifier of the Cloud Functions service (managed in the application state) to create the Load Balancer resources (Load Balancer resources are managed in it's own state file).